# Edit standalone.xml in Openshift v3.X

Tags: openshift, wildfly

I have a web app deployed in Openshift v3 with s2i binary that starts with shipped standalone-openshift.xml and datasource injected by config map.

I tried to customize datasource by modifying the standalone-openshift.xml, than I triggered deployment, but wildfly failed to start with the following error:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) WFLYCTL0013: 
Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("jdbc-driver" => "oracle")
]) - failure description: "WFLYCTL0212: Duplicate resource [
    (\"subsystem\" => \"datasources\"),
    (\"jdbc-driver\" => \"oracle\")
]
```

After I add standalone-openshift.xml, I wiped out every datasource reference into the deployment.yaml.

Any idea?

Comment: you try to add the oracle jdbc-driver twice in your standalone. 
but what you want to do is either edit the existing datasource or add an additional one. as the driver is a different configuration, you do not need to add it again as well. it gets referenced from the datasource. so as oracle is already configured your deployment goes wrong due to a second declaration of oracle driver

Comment: maybe does eap71-openshift include already oracle driver? I think not, because I copy oracle driver and module.xml with s2i

Answer (score 0):

I found out what is the problem: a workmate of mine, set up a gradle task to launch s2i with an install script to copy some stuff and configure oracle driver.